# Casting exceptions when rethrowing in Java

Tags: java, exception, casting

Compare these two methods:

```
void foo() throws SomeSuperException {
    try {
        //...
    } catch (SomeSuperException e) {
        if (e instanceof SomeSubException) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

void bar() throws SomeSubException {
    try {
        //...
    } catch (SomeSuperException e) {
        if (e instanceof SomeSubException) {
            throw (SomeSubException) e;
        }
    }
}
```

Aside from the method signatures (bar can declare `throws SomeSubException` instead of `throws SomeSuperException`), is there any practical difference between the two methods?

**To be clear:** I'm aware that this is a horrible approach to exception handling, and should not be done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case, externally the caller doesn't know about your specific `SomeSubException`, so some detail is lost in translation.

Answer (score 1):

No there's no (big) difference.
From the ordinary it's the best choice to throw the most specific exception,
no the super or broader one. This allows you to handle more cases in the overlaying catchBlock.

Comment: It really depends, if the sub exception is linked to the details of the implementation, it might be a good idea to throw the super exception to hide those details to the callers.

Comment: @assylias: so you're saying there's an exception to the rule?  :-)